# load problem with qiskit package - _fblas

Tags: python, qiskit

Trying to run the code from https://qiskit.org/textbook,
(https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-prerequisites/setting-the-environment.html)
I loaded the packages, but trying to run their sample code:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, assemble, Aer
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

from qiskit_textbook.widgets import binary_widget
```

I get the errors:

```
E:\PLang\Python37\python.exe D:/Plang/Workspace/QCompDemo/qcAdder.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Plang/Workspace/QCompDemo/qcAdder.py", line 7, in <module>
    from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, assemble, Aer
  ...
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "E:\PLang\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 215, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have these loaded:

```
qiskit                             0.26.2
qiskit-aer                         0.8.2
qiskit-aqua                        0.9.1
qiskit-ibmq-provider               0.13.1
qiskit-ignis                       0.6.0
qiskit-terra                       0.17.4
qiskit-textbook                    0.1.0
mypy                               0.761
mkl                                2021.2.0
scipy                              1.4.1
```

Other similar issues report that one should install an augmented version of scipy (?) from ([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)), but there are 30+ versions there, and it is not clear which one to install. And would this fix the _fblas DLL problem?

Comment: Hi, I have a few questions. I followed exactly what the page "Setting up your env" (the link you put) said for the install, and I did not run into your error at all. Did you do exactly this, or did you do the setting another way? Also, are the list of packages you put there the only packages you have installed in your env? Because by installing via the instructions, I have a lot more packages than this, plus all versions of the Qiskit packages matching yours, BUT I have 1.6.1 for scipy and I don't have those mypy and mkl. Basically, could you specify how you did the install? :)

Comment: @Lena - I downloaded their qiskit-textbook-master and installed it using their instructions. That seems to be all that is needed (?). I am using PyCharm (Jetbrains), and then as it does the imports, gives the _fblas error. Actually, I think that error is not directly related to qiskit, since many other reports of this problem are from other packages and applications. It seems to be a scipy issue. Maybe I should re-post in that context. Yes, I have many other packages installed, just trying to list the (seemingly) relevant ones.

Comment: Since this is not really qiskit related, but an issue with scipy (other than it being part of their install instructions), I will re-post for that.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm; upgrading to Python 3.8 (from 3.7) fixed it.